# SQL Insert issue

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I got this weird issue, can't figure out how to solve it.
My table has these columns (in this order):

- ID (uniqueidentifier)
- UserID (uniqueidentifier)
- JobID (uniqueidentifier)
- Archive (bit)

I get this error-message:

```
Msg 8169, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.

INSERT INTO AcceptedJobs VALUES 
(NEWID(),
CONVERT(uniqueidentifier,'32c5a126-a063-4d5c-98f5-0b8f9b18dc04'),
CONVERT(uniqueidentifier,'5d454187-b45d40b4-b90b-06a8662de634'),
0)
```

SQL-Azure

Comment: post the code that gave the error

Comment: Hmm how could i forget that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second string can't be converted to `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` datatype. I'm guessing that you are missing a `-`:

```
INSERT INTO AcceptedJobs VALUES 
(NEWID(),
CONVERT(uniqueidentifier,'32c5a126-a063-4d5c-98f5-0b8f9b18dc04'),
CONVERT(uniqueidentifier,'5d454187-b45d-40b4-b90b-06a8662de634'),
0)
```

I tested this and it works, though I'm not sure if its the same UID that you need.

Comment: Thank you! Didn't notice that!